# Проблемы с проверкой подписи драйвера в Visual Studio

Tags: c++, c, драйвер

Пытаюсь скомпилировать пример простейшего драйвера с MSDN:

```
#include <ntddk.h>
#include <wdf.h>

DRIVER_INITIALIZE DriverEntry;
EVT_WDF_DRIVER_DEVICE_ADD KmdfHelloWorldEvtDeviceAdd;

NTSTATUS DriverEntry(_In_ PDRIVER_OBJECT  DriverObject, _In_ PUNICODE_STRING 
RegistryPath)

{
    NTSTATUS status;
    WDF_DRIVER_CONFIG config;

    KdPrintEx((DPFLTR_IHVDRIVER_ID, DPFLTR_INFO_LEVEL, "KmdfHelloWorld: 
    DriverEntry\n"));
    WDF_DRIVER_CONFIG_INIT(&config, KmdfHelloWorldEvtDeviceAdd);
    status = WdfDriverCreate(DriverObject, RegistryPath, 
    WDF_NO_OBJECT_ATTRIBUTES, &config, WDF_NO_HANDLE);
    return status;
}

NTSTATUS KmdfHelloWorldEvtDeviceAdd(_In_ WDFDRIVER Driver, _Inout_ 
PWDFDEVICE_INIT DeviceInit)

{
    NTSTATUS status;
    WDFDEVICE hDevice;
    UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(Driver);

    KdPrintEx((DPFLTR_IHVDRIVER_ID, DPFLTR_INFO_LEVEL, "KmdfHelloWorld: 
    KmdfHelloWorldEvtDeviceAdd\n"));
    status = WdfDeviceCreate(&DeviceInit, WDF_NO_OBJECT_ATTRIBUTES, &hDevice);
    return status;
}
```

Но получаю ошибку: inf2cat signability test failed

Вывод утилиты:

```
Inf2Cat Tool Output:
........................
Signability test failed.

Errors:
22.9.7: DriverVer set to a date in the future (postdated DriverVer not 
allowed) in KMDF Driver1\kmdfdriver1.inf.

Warnings:
None
```

Все, что связано с датой в kmdfdriver1.inf:

```
[Version]
Signature="$WINDOWS NT$"
Class=Sample ; TODO: edit Class
ClassGuid={78A1C341-4539-11d3-B88D-00C04FAD5171} ; TODO: edit ClassGuid
Provider=%ManufacturerName%
CatalogFile=KMDFDriver1.cat
DriverVer = 12/01/2017,1.8.23.568
```

Дата выставлена такая же, какую показывает Windows. Что сделал не так?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Проблема была в следующем:

Компиляция происходила с использованием локального времени, а Inf2Cat использовала GMT. Отключил в настройках проекта параметр uselocaltime и проблема решилась.